# Multi-tiered sitemap?

Tags: seo, sitemap

From: http://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.html :

> If you want to list more than 50,000 URLs, you must create multiple
>   Sitemap files <...> If you do provide multiple Sitemaps, you should
>   then list each Sitemap file in a Sitemap index file. Sitemap index
>   files may not list more than 50,000 Sitemaps and must be no larger
>   than 10MB (10,485,760 bytes) and can be compressed. You can have more
>   than one Sitemap index file.

Is it possible then to create a 3- or more tiered chain? For example:

**//mysite/sitemap.xml** is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sitemapindex xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
    <sitemap>
        <loc>http://mysite/sitemaps/index.xml</loc>
        <lastmod>2004-10-01T18:23:17+00:00</lastmod>
    </sitemap>
</sitemapindex>
```

**//mysite/sitemaps/index.xml** is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sitemapindex xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
    <sitemap>
        <loc>http://mysite/sitemaps/sitemap-lm.xml.gz</loc>
    </sitemap>
    <sitemap>
        <loc>http://mysite/sitemaps/sitemap-1.xml.gz</loc>
    </sitemap>
   ....
</sitemapindex>
```

and  **//mysite/sitemaps/sitemap-lm.xml.gz** is a normal gzipped XML-file, passing validation and so on.

Id est:

> /robots.txt -> /sitemap.xml -> /sitemaps/sitemapslist.xml ->
>   /sitemaps/sitemap-1.xml.gz

The specification doesn't give a **clear** answer.

Google and personal input both have yelded inconclusive and contradictory answers, ranging from "sure, why not" to "no, because nobody does it that way".

Any ideas would be welcome!

Comment: `You can have more than one Sitemap index file.` gives clue

Comment: @Lashane , can I use chained sitemap index?

Comment: yes, why not, standard says you can use multiple indexes

Answer (score 0):

No, I don't think you can proceed that way, but there is nothing preventing you from declaring multiple `<sitemapindex>` sitemaps in your `robots.txt` with multiple `sitemap:<path-to-a-sitemap-index-sitemap>` lines in it.

Your `robots.txt` would be the 1st level, the listed `<sitemapindex>` sitemaps would be the second level, and the real sitemaps would be the 3rd level.